# PHP : Cut Direction from string

Tags: php

I have string like :

```
 /home/kamal/public_html/clients/book/wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_uploads/1983322598/k.jpg
```

i need to get only

```
wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_uploads/1983322598/k.jpg
```

How can do that ?

Comment: Is `/home/kamal/public_html/clients/book/` the same in every string? A simple way would be `$string = str_replace('/home/kamal/public_html/clients/book/', '', $string);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "/home/kamal/public_html/clients/book/wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_uploads/1983322598/k.jpg";

$exploded_string = explode("/", $string);
//$exploded_string is now an array of: home, kamal, public_html.... ...k.jpg

$n = array_search("wp-content", $exploded_string);
//$n is now the index of "wp-content" in the $exploded_string array

$new_path = array_slice($exploded_string, $n);
$new_path = implode("/", $new_path);

echo $new_path;
```